# Pivot not combining rows on ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

The table I am attempting to pivot looks like this:

```
|     Timestamp    | Userid | Event | message   | Id |
------------------------------------------------------
| 2016-09-01 08:40 | 600    | 0     | Created   | 1  |
| 2016-09-01 08:41 | 600    | 1     | Started   | 1  |
| 2016-09-01 08:42 | 600    | 2     | Completed | 1  |
| 2016-09-01 10:01 | 601    | 0     | Created   | 2  |
| 2016-09-01 10:01 | 601    | 1     | Started   | 2  |
```

And here is the code I am using to attempt to pivot the table.

```
with mytable as (
select TimeStamp
    ,UserId
    ,event
    ,message
    ,Id
from dbname.tablename
where TimeStamp between '2016-09-01' and '2016-10-01'
)
select Id
    ,[0] as created
    ,[1] as started
    ,[2] as completed
    ,[4] as mismatch_reported
    ,[5] as reqstd_qty_updated
    ,[6] as starting_update
    ,[7] as replaced
from mytable
pivot
(max(timestamp) for event in ([0],[1],[2],[4],[5],[6],[7])) as pivottable
```

My expected result would be:

```
| Id |      created     |      started     |    completed    | mismatch_reported | ... | replaced |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 2016-09-01 08:40 | 2016-09-01 08:41 | 2016-09-01 8:42 | NULL              | ... | NULL     |
| 2  | 2016-09-01 10:01 | 2016-09-01 10:01 | NULL            | NULL              | ... | NULL     |
```

The results I am getting are splitting all of the timestamps into their own separate row with the ID like so:

```
| Id |      created     |      started     |    completed    | mismatch_reported | ... | replaced |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 2016-09-01 08:40 | NULL             | NULL            | NULL              | ... | NULL     |
| 1  | NULL             | 2016-09-01 08:41 | NULL            | NULL              | ... | NULL     |
| 1  | NULL             | NULL             | 2016-09-01 8:42 | NULL              | ... | NULL     |
| 2  | 2016-09-01 10:01 | NULL             | NULL            | NULL              | ... | NULL     |
| 2  | NULL             | 2016-09-01 10:01 | NULL            | NULL              | ... | NULL     |
```

I have no idea why it is doing this. I am a rookie when it comes to pivoting, but all the examples I have seen show the pivot command working as I would expect it to work.

What is going wrong with the pivot statement in this query?

### ______________________________________________________________

Thanks to TT. for linking me to this! - This will generate an example table for you to troubleshoot

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   TimeStamp VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,UserId    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,event     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,message   VARCHAR(31) NOT NULL
  ,Id        INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(TimeStamp,UserId,event,message,Id) VALUES ('2016-09-01 04:40:11.343',187,0,'Created',5);
INSERT INTO mytable(TimeStamp,UserId,event,message,Id) VALUES ('2016-09-01 04:40:30.297',187,1,'Started',5);
INSERT INTO mytable(TimeStamp,UserId,event,message,Id) VALUES ('2016-09-01 04:40:30.560',187,2,'Completed',5);
INSERT INTO mytable(TimeStamp,UserId,event,message,Id) VALUES ('2016-09-01 04:42:00.167',238,1,'Started',6);
INSERT INTO mytable(TimeStamp,UserId,event,message,Id) VALUES ('2016-09-01 04:41:59.667',238,2,'Completed',6);
INSERT INTO mytable(TimeStamp,UserId,event,message,Id) VALUES ('2016-09-01 04:41:55.670',238,0,'Created',6);
INSERT INTO mytable(TimeStamp,UserId,event,message,Id) VALUES ('2016-09-01 04:42:09.297',238,0,'Created',7);
INSERT INTO mytable(TimeStamp,UserId,event,message,Id) VALUES ('2016-09-01 04:42:11.403',238,2,'Completed',7);
INSERT INTO mytable(TimeStamp,UserId,event,message,Id) VALUES ('2016-09-01 04:42:11.843',238,1,'Started',7);
```

Comment: The issue you mention is not reproducible with the query provided. Most probably the actual query contains more fields in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: You are not showing the seconds/milliseconds if you timestamp column. Sure they are irrelevant here?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos The actual query does contain more fields in the select clause, but I ran my edited-for-SE query and ended up with the same issue.

Comment: @TT. Seconds/milliseconds should not be important? They are included in the actual data, but I didn't feel they would have an impact on the results here.

Comment: I've already tested your query with the sample data provided and I get the expected result on my end.

Comment: Please provide sample data setup as outlined in this article: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/). Also add the *exact* query you have that produces the incorrect result (based on the sample data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you have some addition column in your actual table on which you want to do pivot, if thats the case try like this:
create a derived table (SourceTable), to filter the columns you want as specific.

```
declare @a table ([Timestamp] datetime, [Event] int, Id int, a int )
insert into @a values ( '2016-09-01 08:40' , 0   ,   1 , 1 )
insert into @a values (  '2016-09-01 08:41',  1 ,     1 , 2 )
insert into @a values (  '2016-09-01 08:42',  2 ,     1 , 3  )
insert into @a values (  '2016-09-01 10:01',  0  ,    2  , 4 )
insert into @a values (  '2016-09-01 10:01' , 1  ,    2  , 5 )

 select Id
    ,[0] as created
    ,[1] as started
    ,[2] as completed
from
( 
select [Timestamp], [Event], Id from @a
) as SourceTable
pivot
(max(timestamp) for event in ([0],[1],[2])) as pivottable;
```

@a- your actual table and SourceTable- derived table

Comment: was this the issue ??

Comment: So what you are saying is that I should replace the line `from mytable` with `from (select timestamp, event, id from mytable)`?